# STOP signal as node in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

There is a way to obtain a ''STOP signal '' as node in tikzpicture?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with "as node"?

Comment: I need a command that definie the stop in figure

       `\tikzstyle{STOP} = {...........}` 

In order to be able to write 

        `\node[STOP]`

and to have as output the image. @Heiko

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

with red border is simple...

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
stop/.style = {regular polygon, regular polygon sides=8,
      draw=red, double, double distance=2mm, ultra thick,
      fill=red, font=\Huge\bfseries, text=white,
      inner sep=0mm, node contents={STOP}}
                    ]
\node[stop];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```